# Handler to increase count in AsnycTask on the background isn't delaying

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-handler

I am trying to increase my count on the background periodically.

This is my handler and doInBackground function in AsyncTask

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    while(true){
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {




public void run() {

             count++;

            }
        }, 10000);

    }
}
```

When i execute this task, it waits for 10 seconds then it starts to increase count very fast ( nearly 2k per second ). I want to increase count 1 for every 10 seconds.

Comment: Then put a Thread.sleep inside the Handler... What you currently do is wait for 10 seconds, then run a while true loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while(true)` loop is causing this. You are essentially creating a new thread inside another thread, throwing the timing off. You can solve this problem by removing the `while(true)` and calling `doInBackground()` inside `run()`. This is how the handler keeps looping. Here is an example:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
            count++;
            doInBackground("");
        }
    }, 10000);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use handler if you want to do something every X seconds.

```
private final static int INTERVAL = 10000;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable()
{
     @Override 
     public void run() {
          doSomething();
          mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, INTERVAL);
     }
};

void startRepeatingTask()
{
    mHandlerTask.run(); 
}

void stopRepeatingTask()
{
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mHandlerTask);
}
```

Comment: is handler running on background like AsyncTask? I mean if i use this code on main activity, won't it start to loop and stop my main activity?

Comment: no ,handler  doesn't need extra thread to keep tracking when firing the event